# How to use a xaml trigger or styleselector to adjust size of control based upon available space

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make a button that is styled to change its layout to make itself smaller based upon how much space is available.

These buttons will always have a stackpanel with an image and a textblock within it. I'm aiming to be able to define 3-4 different styles for these buttons, each resulting in a different button size.

For each button image, I have 4 versions if the image in different resolutions. 16, 32, 48 and 64. These images are stored in different folders; i.e. Images\Icons\16\Add.png and Images\Icons\32\Add.png. Both of those images are the same, just different sizes. I've chosen to use multiple sizes because I found that just having one image and scaling its size caused it to be rather blurry.

To facilitate choosing different sized images, I've created a converter which I use when binding the image source:

```
class ImagePathResolutionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Image sender = (Image)value;
        int imageSize = (parameter != null) ? (parameter is int) ? (int)parameter : (parameter is string) ? Int32.Parse((string)parameter) : 16 : 16;
        Uri returnImage = new Uri(String.Format(@"Images\Icons\{0}\{1}", imageSize, sender.Tag as string), UriKind.Relative);
        return returnImage;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

The binding looks like this:

```
<Setter Property="Source" 
        Value="{Binding ., 
                Converter={StaticResource ImagePathResolutionConverter}, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                ConverterParameter='16'}" 
/>
```

Using this set up means that I can pass 16, 32, 48 or 64 to the ConverterParameter, and the appropriate image path will be returned.

Now, for this example, I have two styles;

Big:

```
<!-- Big Button Container Style -->
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MultiResButton_Big">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Style.Resources>
        <!-- Button.StackPanel Style -->
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical" />
            <Style.Resources>
                <!-- Button.StackPanel.Image Style -->
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="None" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 2 5 0" />
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource ImagePathResolutionConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, ConverterParameter='32'}" />
                </Style>
                <!-- Button.StackPanel.TextBlock Style -->
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0 5 2" />
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

... and Small

```
<!-- Small Button Container Style -->
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MultiResButton_Small">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Style.Resources>
        <!-- Button.StackPanel Style -->
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
            <Style.Resources>
                <!-- Button.StackPanel.Image Style -->
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="None" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 2" />
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource ImagePathResolutionConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, ConverterParameter='16'}" />
                </Style>
                <!-- Button.StackPanel.TextBlock Style -->
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 5 2 5" />
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

The XAML for one of these buttons is :

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MultiResButton_Big}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Tag="Multi.png" />
        <TextBlock Text="Button Text" />
    </StackPanel>            
</Button>
```

At the moment, I can set a button to either or these, and the results are a big or small button. Now I just need to work out how to determin when to use which, and how to do so programatically.

The way I see it, I have two options: Combine both styles into one and use a trigger of some sort, OR create a styleSelector class and let it choose which style to use.

My problem is that I'm at a loss as to how to programatically determine which style to use. I've found the 'RenderSize.Width' gets set to 0 when the button is pushed beyond the visible range of the container. My issue is that when 5 buttons are outside the visible bounds of the container, setting the 5 to use the smaller style won't help... I'll have to also use the smaller size for other visible buttons in order to 'make room' for the 5 that are outside the bounds.

I'd be happy with setting the style for all buttons within a container... the moment one buttons renderSize.Width = 0, knock all of the sibling buttons down to on style size lower...

Is what I'm attempting even possible? Would I have to create a custom container in order to override the rendering of all of the child controls? I would rather avoid that if I can... but I can't see any other possible way...

As an example of what I'm trying to accomplish, open Word or Excel 2007/2010, and slowly resize the window to make it smaller. As you so so, the buttons in the ribon 'shrink' to make more room.

I would appreciate any thoughts on whether I'm approaching this from the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a second converter to bind the style.

Create a IMultiValueConverter that takes two values, ActualWidth and the element that the calculations will be based on (in my example, I am using Window):

```
class ImageButtonStyleSelectorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region IMultiValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Double actualWidth = values[0] as Double? ?? 0;
        FrameworkElement element = values[1] as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null)
        {
            // perform calculations and return button size (using even/odd for illustration purposes)
            if (element.Width % 2 == 0)
            {
                return element.Resources["MultiResButton_Small"];
            }
            else
            {
                return element.Resources["MultiResButton_Big"];
            }
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then, change your button to use the converter to choose the style:

```
        <Button>
            <Button.Style>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyleSelectorConverter}"
                              FallbackValue="{StaticResource MultiResButton_Big}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}" Path="."/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.Style>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Tag="Multi.png" />
                <TextBlock Text="Button Text" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
```

I added the FallbackValue because otherwise, I could not see either style from design view.